# xcode build script on Mac OS X not working because env node not found / login not working, too

Tags: linux, xcode, macos, bash

I'm using a crontab like this

```
* * * * * PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin cd /Users/kaiserpatrick/Documents/web-app && ./build.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I tried some things with `echo "1" | login kaiserpatrick` or `login -f command` or without the `PATH` variable.

But nothing works.

Each time i've got this error.

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the script header to some thing like this ones. - But not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#!/usr/bin/node
```

I dont know why apple cant use a simple bashrc file or profile file ...

But none of them exists in ~. No profile, no bashrc no ......

The only file is /etc/bashrc. But if i append `. /etc/bashrc` on crontab it doesn't work, too.

Really bad morning :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo $PATH` in normal logged in shell.

Then prepend a `PATH=` with the result above to your cronjob/crontab and on the line end a `;`. After this ; you can add your script or your command.

Then it work's!